# Как сохранить картинку, полученную по ссылке, в модель?

Tags: python, django

Как сохранить картинку, полученную по ссылке, в модель?

```
def ajax_link_download_imgDef(request):


    if request.method == 'GET':
        

        # получит ссылку на изображение
        img_url = request.GET['link']

        img = requests.get(img_url, stream = True)
        img_file = open('img.png', 'wb')        
        img_file.write(img.content)
        
        # сохранит (создав модель)
        obj = pattern_save_imgModel.objects.create(field_img = img_file, )

        # получить название сохранённой картинки
        # img_name = str(obj.field_img)

        # удалит файл с изображением
        img_file.close()


        return HttpResponse(MEDIA_URL + 'АВА_spocg9R.jpg')
```

в данном случае выдает ошибку

```
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute '_committed'
[01/Sep/2020 14:59:44] "GET /ved/post/ajax!menu_link_download_img/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fis3-ssl.mzstatic.com%2Fimage%2Fthumb%2FPurple113%2Fv4%2F41%2Ff8%2F9e%2F41f89e30-c098-fc38-b2d5-45a792b7c1fb%2FAppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-0-7-0-0-85-220.png%2F1200x630wa.png&_=1598961569926 HTTP/1.1" 500 17069
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732150/django-shell-image-upload-io-bufferedreader-no-attribute-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FieldFile.saveМетод должен быть вызван с экземпляром django.core.files.File, а не встроенный в ручку питон файла. Измените вызов сохранения на:

```
from django.core.files import File

imagead.full_photo.save("NowHiring.jpg", File(open("C:\\NowHiring.jpg", "rb")))
```

За ответ благодарю  [Victor VosMottor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/337540/victor-vosmottor)

Comment: Добавьте перевод основных идей ответа в текстовом виде в ответ. Ответы-ссылки могут инвалидироваться и становиться бесполезными